# Making body margins bigger but keeping site centered

Tags: html, css

I am extremely new to html and css. I wanted to know how to make my body margins bigger so the other header can fit in the same line as my first header.

```
<DOCTYPE!>
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>
This tag is for making a header.
<h1>
<h1 style="margin-top: -60px; margin-left: 500px;">
Second h1 tag that i am putting in
</h1>
</div>
</html>
```

Css:

```
.container{
    width: 700px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h1 style="display:inline-block;">
This tag is for making a header.
<h1>
<h1 style="display:inline-block;">
Second h1 tag that i am putting in
</h1>
```

dont set margin `display:inline-block` will make both h1 in one line

Comment: This is better than ABForce's example, because you're not forcing all H1s within "container" class divs to be inline-block - you're better setting the style inline or creating a new class (call it whatever you want, "inlineHeader" for example.

Comment: i know setting new class is good i was just making him clear the doubt so i used it in inline

Comment: @Stan It's recommended to not using inline styling via `style` property of the element. However I agreed with you, my CSS rule will be applied to all `h1`s inside `.container` but it was just an example for **demonstrating** and it's not intended to be exactly copied into the real application source codes

Comment: Gotcha, ABForce - I agree.